# React Native Issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I am building a react native app that uses the Wordpress api. I am having problems displaying the cart and receive this error.

> Object {} error [Error: Request failed with status code 404]
>   undefined

I have tried everything and have figures it might be a problem with Axios...

Please advise me on what I can do...

CartAction.js

```js
import *  as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';
import CartApi from '../api/CartApi';

export function getCart() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return CartApi.getCart().then(cart => {
            dispatch(getCartSuccess(cart));
        }).catch(err => {
            //TODO:get correct error msg
            console.log(err.error);
        })
    };
}

function getCartSuccess(cart) {
    return {
        type: types.GET_CART_SUCCESS,
        cart
    };
}

export function addToCart(product, quantity) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return CartApi.addToCart(product, quantity).then(cartUpdate => {
            dispatch(addToCartSuccess(cartUpdate));
        }).catch(err => {
            //TODO:get correct error msg
            console.log('error',err);
        })
    };
}

function addToCartSuccess(cartUpdate) {
    return {
        type: types.ADD_TO_CART_SUCCESS,
        cartUpdate
    };
}
```

CartPage.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import * as CartAction from '../../actions/CartAction';

class CartPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cart: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.CartAction.getCart();
  }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.key;

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.cart)
    const cartObject = this.props.cart;
    var cartArray = [];
    Object.keys(cartObject).forEach(function(key) {
      cartArray.push(cartObject[key]);
    });
    const Items = <FlatList contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
      data={cartArray}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      renderItem={({ item }) => 
      // <TouchableHighlight style={{width:'50%'}} onPress={() => navigate("Product", { product: item })} underlayColor="white">
        <View style={styles.lineItem} >
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item.product_image}} />
          <Text style={styles.text}>{item.product_name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{item.quantity}</Text>
        </View>
      // </TouchableHighlight>
      }
    />;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Items}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  lineItem: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  list: {
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  image: {
    width: 50, 
    height: 50
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    padding: 5
  }
})

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
  cart: state.cart
 };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return {
  CartAction: bindActionCreators(CartAction, dispatch)
 };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CartPage);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you paste your CartAction code ?

Comment: I changed it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does it bring anything back in this part of the code?
 
        return CartApi.getCart().then(cart => {
            dispatch(getCartSuccess(cart));
        })

If not, you should have a look on the CartApi file. 404 means that that what is requested not found...so probably something is wrong with the URL you try to hit, or parameters that you send for your request...